# SQL/DDL - Needing a unique column from time to time

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, duplicates, unique

this is my current table

```
-- Table structure for table `test`

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `emp_number` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `some_value_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `some_value_2` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
    
-- Indexes for table `test`

ALTER TABLE `test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `emp_number` (`emp_number`);
```

Because of the unique column "emp_number", no rows with an existing value of emp_number cant be inserted.

Is there a way to ignore the unique column and insert the row if i really want to?

I wont like to change the tables structure (dynamically).

## Why i defined the emp_number as unique

We got customers who would like to have only unique emp_numbers, but we got also customers now, who got the same emp_number for multiple employees. I do know that this is bull****. I dont want to alter the table of existing ones.

Thank you in advance, Louis.

Comment: Could you explain why you have defined a unique key on `emp_number` if you don't actually want one?

Comment: No.  You cannot violate the database rules on data integrity, unless you drop those rules.

Comment: okay - i can drop the unique-status for the emp_number column, but how can i prevent inserting a record with an already existing emp_number value (when i need to)? Doing a SELECT immediatly before the INSERT wont be the real right solution...